# How to embed tables and figures so they are not included in word count

Tags: microsoft-word, word-count

I need to embed the tables and figures in my thesis so that they are not included when the words are electronically counted. Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure it's straightforward but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can include the parts of the text you don't want to appear in the word count in a text box. Then to see the word count click on that part of the toolbar and you will get the following screen. Untick the option to include textboxes, footnotes and endnotes in the calculation.

[image]